# Asp.net js script with jquery problem

Tags: asp.net, jquery, events, telerik

At my asp.net project I use telerik asp.net ajax controls set. so at my masterpage I have.

```
<telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server"/>
```

Also I would like use some jquery functions:

```
     <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
     <div class="pnlFind" style="display:none;>             
     <asp:Label runat="server" ID="btA">test</asp:Label>
     </div>
     <p class="test">click</p> 
     <script type="text/jscript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
           $('.test').click(function () {
             alert('Handler for .click() called.');
             return false;
        });
  });
 </script>   
 </asp:Content>
```

But this code doesn't work. Nothing fires after clicking

.
When i exec this js at firebug console all works well[got alert]. Why at first page loading jquery script doesn't work???

May be i can't mix ms(telerik) ajax and jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
<script type="text/jscript">
```

You should have this (if you want it to work cross-browser):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

`jscript` is the IE implmentation of JavaScript, though some browsers will run that MIME type of script block (IE/Chrome/Opera, maybe others)....Firefox isn't one of them :)  `text/javascript` will run for all browsers.